# I will be given

Tags: grammar, usage

- I hope, I ***will be given*** this chance

Is it correct use of passive voice?

Can *"we be given"* (smth)?

Is it grammatically correct or not?

And is it isn't, how can we change the structure of the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct, but lose the comma.  If the comma is there, it is matched with another comma before *I hope* - which obviously is not there, because the sentence starts there.

> I hope I will be given this chance.

Here is a version with the comma in place, but not being an error:

> And after all of this effort, I hope, I will be given this chance.

And just to add, it is equivalent to say

> I hope I am given this chance.